# выполнение условия if наоборот

Tags: python, синтаксис

как сделать выполнение условия if наоборот? 
мне нужно так,что когда файла нет, то он создается.
Тоесть часть после else должна выполнятся первой

Есть код

```
import os # для проверки существования файла

if os.path.exists('test.txt'): # проверка файла test.txt на его существование
    # файл существует
else:
    # файла нет . Создание файла.
```

Comment: `if not <condition>`

Comment: вот так правильно ? if  not os.path.exists('test.txt')

Comment: проще попробовать ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Логический оператор `not`(отрицание).

```
if not os.path.exists('test.txt'):
```